# Radical of ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

My question is pretty easy, however I got stuck to get the answer.

> Assume the polynomial ring $ R=\mathbb Z[x,y]$ and $I=(xy)$ be an ideal of $R$. I want to compute the radical of $I$.

I am trying to show that $I$ is prime ideal since I know tha radical for prime ideal will be the prime ideal itself. Anyway, what is the radical of $I$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that $I$ is prime? It seems like $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ are nonzero elements in the quotient ring $R/I$, but $\bar{x}\bar{y}=\bar{0}$.

Comment: I do not assume $I$ Prime ideal. I want to find $ rad(I)$

Answer (score 1):

If $P\in Rad(I)$ then there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $P^k=xyQ$. And obviously, $k>0$.

Consequently, $x$ and $y$ divide $P^k$.

But $x$ and $y$ are irreducible. Hence, by Euclid's lemma, each of them must divide $P$.

Finally, since $x$ and $y$ are coprime, their lcm (namely $xy$) must divide $P$. So $P\in I$.

Hoping it's correct ...

Comment: Please, what is the Euclid's Lemma

Comment: @Team - Euclid's lemma says that if an irreducible element (of any GCD domain) divides a product, then it divides at least one factor.

Comment: You mean lcm and not gcd.

Comment: @Mohan - of course, sorry for the mistake ... Editing

Comment: No, [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma) doesn't state what you say. That one is a well known property of GCD domains, namely irreducible = prime.

Comment: Btw, you don't even need this. The elements $x,y$ are prime.